# How to scroll to image[x] in ScrollView at the first time open screen?

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

How to scroll to image[x] in `ScrollView` at the first time component load?

I want when we open this screen, `ScrollView` will scroll to the 4th image.

This is my [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@zhenguet/animated)

```
export default function App() {
  const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0));
  const imageRef = createRef(scrollX);

  useEffect(() => {
    imageRef.current?.scrollTo(new Animated.Value(3));
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.scrollContainer}>
        <ScrollView
          ref={imageRef}
          horizontal={true}
          pagingEnabled
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          onScroll={Animated.event(
            [
              {
                nativeEvent: {
                  contentOffset: {
                    x: scrollX.current,
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
            { useNativeDriver: false }
          )}
          scrollEventThrottle={1}
        >
          {children}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scrollTo accept separate compoenents. You don't need to use animated component and the onScroll method for react scrollview. Just enter {x: value, animated: true} in scrollTo as it accepts object

Here is the code updated from snack:

```html
import React, { useRef, useEffect, createRef } from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  Animated,
  Dimensions,
} from "react-native";

const images = new Array(6).fill(
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556740749-887f6717d7e4"
);

export const WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;

export default function App() {
  const imageRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    imageRef.current?.scrollTo({x: WIDTH * 3});
  },[]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.scrollContainer}>
        <ScrollView
          ref={imageRef}
          horizontal={true}
          pagingEnabled
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        >
          {images.map((image, imageIndex) => {
            return (
              <View
                style={{
                  width: WIDTH,
                  height: 250,
                }}
                key={imageIndex}
              >
                <ImageBackground source={{ uri: image }} style={styles.card}>
                  <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.infoText}>
                      {"Image - " + imageIndex}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </ImageBackground>
              </View>
            );
          })}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  scrollContainer: {
    height: 300,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  card: {
    flex: 1,
    marginVertical: 4,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    borderRadius: 5,
    overflow: "hidden",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  textContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0, 0.7)",
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
    paddingVertical: 8,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  infoText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
});
```